# How cheat app to hide root

Tags: java, android, root, rooted-device

my device is rooted.
I created a way to check root.

```
public class RootUtil {
public boolean isDeviceRooted() {
    return checkRootMethod1() || checkRootMethod2() || checkRootMethod3();
}

private boolean checkRootMethod1() {
    String buildTags = android.os.Build.TAGS;
    return buildTags != null && buildTags.contains("test-keys");
}

private boolean checkRootMethod2() {
    String[] paths = { "/system/app/Superuser.apk", "/sbin/su", "/system/bin/su",
            "/system/xbin/su", "/data/local/xbin/su", "/data/local/bin/su", "/system/sd/xbin/su",
            "/system/bin/failsafe/su", "/data/local/su", "/su/bin/su"};
    for (String path : paths) {
        if (new File(path).exists()) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean checkRootMethod3() {
    Process process = null;
    try {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "/system/xbin/which", "su", "-", "root" });
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        return in.readLine() != null;
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        return false;
    } finally {
        if (process != null) process.destroy();
    }
}
}
```

It show that my device is rooted.

When i installed app such like hide my root, android studio show that my device isn't rooted.

My question -> is a way to cheat app hide my root, or get true information about rooted device?

Comment: check if in installed packages exist popular root hiding programs. And check for Xposed installed (it can't work without root and is used for hiding it)

Comment: There must be a criteria, fulfilment of which says "Phone is Rooted" or otherwise - it could be the existence of `su` in certain locations. It could also be something else, not sure what else it can be. Another point to note is that for an app to have system access, it must either be a system app or have access to su binary.

Comment: Dima i agree with you. I can use PackageManager to check installed hiding programs but list of this programs is infinite.